# Allow drafts in entries field

Tags: relations, entries-field, draft

Is it possible to allow selecting drafts in an entries field? Not drafts of an existing live entry, but drafts that aren't published yet.

The only thing I found is an `ElementCriteriaEvent` [triggered in the `BaseRelationField`](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php#L1003-L1014) class which allows you to add selection criteria for the field, but I couldn't figure out a way to change the allowable statuses using the criteria (by the way, is the syntax for those criteria arrays documented anywhere?).

Here's my attempt which doesn't work:

```php
use craft\events\ElementCriteriaEvent;
use craft\fields\Entries;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(
    Entries::class,
    Entries::EVENT_DEFINE_SELECTION_CRITERIA,
    function (ElementCriteriaEvent $e) {
        $e->criteria = ['status' => ['live', 'draft']];
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drafts` is not a status but an [Element Query parameter](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php#L135-L139) so if you want drafts to be return as well as live entries, you can do:

```php
Event::on(
    \craft\fields\Entries::class,
    \craft\fields\Entries::EVENT_DEFINE_SELECTION_CRITERIA,
    function (\craft\events\ElementCriteriaEvent $e) {
        $e->criteria = ['drafts'=> null];
    }
);
```

Passing `true` would only return Drafts, `false` (default) no Drafts and `null` *takes it out* of the query.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Unfortunately, while drafts now show up for selection, they're thrown out upon saving because the `BaseRelationField::normalizeValue` function doesn't allow drafts. I've opened [an issue on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/9963) about this – hopefully that leads somewhere, as it stands the only way to allow selecting drafts would be to extend the entries field and to modify the `normalizeValue` method to allow drafts.